# Laravel Migration onDelete() Query Exception

Tags: php, sql, laravel, postgresql, laravel-migrations

I have a simple laravel migration with a foreign key.

```
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('smp_posts', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->increments('id');
        $table->integer('project_id')->unsigned();
        // Some other stuff
        $table->foreign('project_id')->references('id')->on('smp_projects')->onDelete('cascade');
    });
}
```

When I run the migrate command `php artisan migrate:refresh`. I get this error:

> Illuminate\Database\QueryException:
>
> SQLSTATE[2BP01]: Dependent objects still exist: 7
>
> ERROR:  cannot drop table smp_projects because other objects depend on it
>       DETAIL:  constraint smp_posts_project_id_foreign on table smp_posts depends on table smp_projects

Normally all childs should be deleted, because I set the `onDelete()` to cascade. Right? What's going wrong?

Comment: Maybe the smp_projects migrations has a date after sms_posts, check the name of the migration.

Comment: No smp_posts comes after smp_projects

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `cascade` option you set applies only when you delete a row. If you drop the table that constraint is not triggered, that's why you get the error.

You should take a look at the [Dependency Tracking](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/ddl-depend.html) section of Postgres docs